# How to call dispatch job inside dispatch job in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a scenario where I want to call a dispatch job inside a job. If the order has been placed in 60 seconds, it will go to the next driver if the driver doesn't respond.

```
public function index()
{
    $order = Order::create([
        'name' => "order1",
        "driver_id" => "1",
        "status" => "0",
        "price" => "500"

    ]);

    dispatch(new OrderPlacedJob($order))->delay(now()->addSecond(30));
}
```

Inside my `OrderPlacedJob`, I am trying to call Orderplacedjob like the following.

```
class OrderPlacedJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $order;

    public function __construct(Order $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }
    
    public function handle()
    {
        $order = $this->order;
        
        if ($this->order->status == '0') {
            $driver_id = $this->order->driver_id + 1;
            $this->order->driver_id = $driver_id;
            $this->order->save();
        }

        OrderPlacedJob::dispatch($order)->delay(now()->addSecond(30));
    }
}
```

It is working for the first time. If a driver with id one is given the order, but if he doesn't respond within a second, the id changes to 2, then it stops and doesn't run for the second time.

Comment: There are so many inconsistencies in your code... Use of single quotes `'` vs double quotes `"`: `'name' => "order1",`, `"driver_id" => "1",`, your numbers are strings `"1"` should be `1`, different syntax on how you Dispatch the job: `dispatch(new OrderPlacedJob($order))->delay(now()->addSecond(30));` vs `OrderPlacedJob::dispatch($order)->delay(now()->addSecond(30));`, etc. The last one _might_ be the reason why it is "stopping", but regardless, please try to be consistent with your code.

Comment: dispatch(new OrderPlacedJob($order))->delay(now()->addSecond(30)); i have changed this inside OrderPlacedjob it still remains the same

Comment: Like I said, that _might_ have been the issue; that was the main thing I saw that looked "incorrect" in your code. It's likely something else, I don't know right now, but I'll look into it when I can, or, hopefully someone else will be able to help in the meantime.

Comment: Stop your queue worker and let it run once to see what happens, then let it run once again. etc  This type of issue is so much easier to debug when you can dump and log actual code.